# Failed to install texlive 2021！

Tags: installing

I tried to install texlive 2021 for several times with all kinds of methods. But it was showed that the installation program couldn't find the path for all the files which had a win32 suffix, like texlive.infra.win32.

Comment: You need to clarify. What did you try? And where are files missing? In Texlive or on your system?

Comment: The installation shows:
Installing [002/285, time/total: 00:03/54:31]: texlive.infra.win32 [2695k]
C:/Users/èa/AppData/Local/Temp/nsu95CC.tmp/install-tl-20210514/install-tl: mkdir(C:/Users/èa/AppData/Local/Temp/c0bjnuKawH/) failed for tree C:/Users/èa/AppData/Local/Temp/c0bjnuKawH/CQTzmzvvbA: Permission denied at C:/Users/èa/AppData/Local/Temp/nsu95CC.tmp/install-tl-20210514/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 942, <STDIN> line 216.
Actually, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: It says "permission denied" that means you are installing as a user that does not have administration rights on your system.

Comment: Emmm..I do use the administration rights  to install texlive...All solutions I could find on the internet are useless ...

Comment: It might be an aggressive antivirus which locks stuff while appempting to analyse it.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. TeX Live Windows does not support non-ascii name for `TEMP` and `TMP`. Please define such as `set TEMP=c:\temp` and `set TMP=c:\temp`, where there shoud be a writable folder `c:\temp`. Or you can make a symbolick link for your non-ascii user name, and redefine TEMP and TMP by using the symbolick link.